# CodeIgniter site how to change base domain?

Tags: php, codeigniter

I want to change domain name of my CodeIgniter site. How can I do this?

Example I have now example.com now I want change it to domain.com.

I have changed config.php file

```
$config['base_url']    = 'http://domain.com';
```

After edit config.php file only home page working with new domain. But other URL working with old domain.

Comment: what links do you have in your view pages? i.e. how are you generating the links? Can you show us that code please?

Comment: Usually CodeIgniter is smart enough to figure out the domain, so you should be okay with `$config['base_url'] = '';` If not, then you need a trailing slash: `http://domain.com/`

Answer (score 0):

You need to use site_url() helper function in order for CI to use the base domain. How do you output links? can you show us an example from a view?

Answer (score 0):

Seems like you have defined absolute path on links of other pages. If you have followed **url** helper of CI, you won't have to do all these. Use `site_url()` function on all your links.

```
 site_url('controller/function/params/params')
```

[URL helper Codeigniter](http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/helpers/url_helper.html)

Answer (score 0):

Do you have a base tag set in your outputted html? Have a look through the head section of your pages for

```
<base href="..." />
```